# Suppose $G$ is a graph with at least one edge then $G$ is a graph with at least $\chi (G) \choose 2$ edges?

Tags: graph-theory

> **Theorem**: Suppose $G=(V,E)$ is a graph with at least one edge i.e $|E| \geq 1$ then $G$ is a graph with at least $\chi (G) \choose 2$
>   edges.

I'm wanting to give a proof of the following theorem but I'm stuck on how to do it. I **do not** want a full solution so please don't post one. I only want some hints so I can get to the proof myself.

What I know/have done so far:

Since $G$ has at least one edge then $\chi(G) \geq 2$. I also know that the number of potential edges on a graph on $n$ vertices is $n \choose 2$ which is similar to $\chi (G) \choose 2$ so maybe there is something to that I don't know.

I'm stuck with how to proceed now any help?

Answer (score 2):

We can prove it by decending inducation.

As you guess  it's true for $\chi =n$.

Suppose it is true for $\chi = t$, and let's prove it for $\chi = t-1$. 
If   $\chi(G)= t-1$, add to $G$ vertex $u$ that is connected by $\textbf{single}$ edge with each of   $t-1$ color class ( that is $d(u) = t-1$).
It's easy to see that $\chi(G\cup u)=t$, since otherwise we can easily prove that $\chi(G)\leq t-2$.

Thus $E(G\cup u)\geq$ $t\choose 2$ $\Rightarrow$ $E(G)+t-1\geq$ $t\choose 2$. Thus
$$ E(G)\geq {t-1\choose 2}$$